# Restful API - Resource creation answer according to HATEOAS

Tags: rest, hateoas

I'm developing a `RESTful` web service and want to follow the `HATEOAS` concept. There are tons of  examples out there on what should a `GET` response look like according to [HATEOAS](http://www.zienit.nl/blog/2010/01/rest/hateoas-by-example), but I couldn't find a good example on response after a successful resource creation.

How should the `HATEOAS` part of the response headers and body look like?

Thanks for help

Comment: What are your resources? How are they related? Are there any parent-child relations?

Comment: hi @LutzHorn, let's say I only have 2 resources: 1. Account, 2.Address. 1 Account can have multiple Addresses, so Address is a subresource of Account.

Comment: Can an Address exist alone or only as a child of an Account? Only if it can exist alone you will need links and HATEOAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most salient piece of information that can be returned from a resource creation request is a `Link` to the resource itself, usually as a `self` link in the response. Other than this the body of the response for creation of a resource could be many things: empty, some information about the resource created or (most likely) a representation of the resource itself.

If the request creates a new resource you should probably be returning a `201 CREATED` status code.